# Spaces in equal signs

Tags: javascript, c#, html, c++

I'm just wondering is there a difference in performance using removing spaces before and after equal signs. Like this two code snippets.

first

```
int i = 0;
```

second

```
int i=0;
```

I'm using the first one, but my friend who is learning html/javascript told me that my coding is inefficient. Is it true in html/javascript? And is it a huge bump in the performance? Will it also be same in c++/c# and other programming languages? And about the indent, he said 3 spaces is better that tab. But I already used to code like this. So I just want to know if he is correct.

Comment: There's a difference in _file size_ (mostly important for javascript), but not performance. In C# the code gets jitted anyway, so spaces or not it does not matter.

Comment: Your friend is very misguided. Also, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: so, in javascript, it will give slight speed in loading/reading the whole script?

Comment: Yes, but don't do it yourself. There are some minifiers out there. Write code so it can be read correctly, then minify a version and use that one in prod. For C#/C++ and the like, readability > micro-optimizations. I'll gladly trade off milliseconds for maintainable code. And it's also good for variable names by the way. Long descriptive names are much better.

Comment: 1) It's mostly opinion. In a compiled language like C++/C#, the spaces should not matter at all. In an interpreted language like JavaScript it *might* make a few microseconds difference. Ask your "friend" for some timing examples proving what he said. I'd ignore him. 2) 3 spaces? I've seen 2 and 4, but 3? Not so much. Set your editor to insert spaces instead of tabs, set it a 4 spaces and enjoy readable code. Tell your friend to do it his way, and you do it yours. Yours is more readable and will be better in the long run. (This opinion and advice is from MY 30 years' experience. YMMV.)

Comment: I think the key to stress in this is parsed vs compiled. When C#, C++, Java and such languages are compiled they no longer use the .cs, .cpp, etc source files whereas the .js files are parsed and read from during runtime. The performance gain in js minimization is in parsetime / download time.

Comment: Note that the former notation allows you to search your code for assignments (`i = `, note the space after the equal sign) and comparisons (`i ==`) separately. With your friend's notation, you could not search for assignments (`i=`) without also finding comparisons (`i==`) or resorting to regular expressions in your search term to exclude a second equal sign. To me, in combination with @jfriend00's answer, this makes a strong argument for your notation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your friend is a bit misguided.

The extra spaces in the code will make a small difference in the size of the JS file which could make a small difference in the download speed, though I'd be surprised if it was noticeable or meaningful.

The extra spaces are unlikely to make a meaningful difference in the time to parse the file.

Once the file is parsed, the extra spaces will not make any difference in execution speed since they are not part of the parsed code.

---

If you really want to optimize download or parse speed, the way to do that is to write your code in the most readable fashion possible for best maintainability and then use a minimizer for the deployed code and this is a standard practice by many web sites.  This will give you the best of both worlds - maintainable, readable code and minimum deployed size.

A minimizer will remove all unnecessary spacing, shorten the names of variables, remove comments, collapse lines, etc... all designed to make the deployed code as small as possible without changing the run-time meaning of the code at all.

---

C++ is a compiled language.  As such, only the compiler that the developer uses sees any extra spaces (same with comments).  Those spaces are gone once the code has been compiled into native code which is what the end-user gets and runs.  So, issues about spaces between elements in a line are simply not applicable at all for C++.

Javascript is an interpreted language.  That means the source code is downloaded to the browser and the browser then parses the code at runtime into some opcode form that the interpreter can run.  The spaces in Javascript will be part of the downloaded code (if you don't use a minimizer to remove them), but once the code is parsed, those extra spaces are not part of the run-time performance of the code.  Thus, the spaces could have a small influence on the download time and perhaps an even smaller influence on the parse time (though I'm guessing unlikely to be measurable or meaningful).   As I said above, the way to optimize this for Javascript is to use spaces to enhance readability in the source code and then run a minimizer over the code to generate a deployed version of the code to minimize the deployed size of the file.  This preserves maximum readability and minimizes download size.

Answer (score 2):

There is little (javascript) to no (c#, c++, Java) difference in performance.  In the compiled languages in particular, the source code compiles to the exact same machine code.

Using spaces instead of tabs can be a good idea, but not because of performance.  Rather, if you aren't careful, use of tabs can result in "tab rot", where there are tabs in some places and spaces in others, and the indentation of the source code depends on your tab settings, making it hard to read.

Comment: I think the key to stress in this is parsed vs compiled. When C#, C++, Java and such languages are compiled they no longer use the .cs, .cpp, etc source files whereas the .js files are parsed and read from during runtime. The performance gain in js minimization is in parsetime / download time.